# Getting Error in Angular 1 due to indentation

Tags: angularjs

I am new with Angular JS and trying to learn. Tried writing a Provider, which is behaving in a strange manner and throwing an error. Could you please help identify the cause of error.

Here is the code which is working fine:

```
myapp.provider('Testing',function(){    
return {
    $get: function() {
        return          {
            add: function(a,b){return a+b;}
        };
    }
};
});
```

And below is the code which is not working fine:

```
myapp.provider('Testing',function(){    
return {
    $get: function() {
        return          
        {
            add: function(a,b){return a+b;}
        };
    }
};
});
```

The Error due to second snippet:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

The error is pointing to this statement: **add: function(a,b){return a+b;}**

The only difference in the two code snippets is the placement of "`{`" for the return statement inside the function for $get definition.

Is there any valid reason for why the placement of "`{`" should matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the placement of "{" after return matters. 
It is a default JavaScript behavior to close a statement automatically at the end of a line. So,

```
return          
        {
            add: function(a,b){return a+b;}
        };
```

The function will return undefined and the next parentheses will be act as  Unexpected token

```
return ;       
            {
                add: function(a,b){return a+b;}
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: its my pleasure